# MSYS Installation - Silent Mode

Tags: mingw, msys

I want to install MSYS silently,(i.e.) I want to install from command line. I tried various option like

```
C:> MSYS-1.0.11-rc-1.exe /S
C:> MSYS-1.0.11-rc-1.exe /s
C:> MSYS-1.0.11-rc-1.exe /silent
```

but none worked, Could anyone help me out with a solution.

-Shiva

Answer (score 1):

You could instead download [an all-in-one zip package of all MSYS packages from the mingw-w64 site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/).

If you feel this is missing updated packages, please contact me, and I'll upload a new all-in-one package.

Comment: @StevenPenny I hid the URL behind blue text. It's not like I can change the URL itself...